# Is it possible to give a background color to a text field in a form?

Tags: html, css

I do not want to set the color to the input field; I want the background color to be set to the text field. Please see the image attached. Like the black color background on the first two fields, I want to color only the first two fields with a background color. The complete form can be given a background color which is not what I want; I want the form to be white in color except for the first two fields.

> [image]

Comment: You can use fieldset tag, or place these two fields in div.

Comment: share your HTML or fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can understand from your given image. You need to give `fieldset` and first two fields should be under `<div>` tag and then you can set `style="background-color:black;"`

for example:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" style="color:green;">
    <fieldset><legend> Personal Details </legend>
    <div style="background-color:black">
First Name: <br>
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name"><br>
Last Name: <br>
<input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
    </div>
Date Of Birth: <br>
    <input type="text" name="dob" placeholder="mm / dd / yy"><br>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

**[JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/Gagan_Gami/Aa9qg/)**  I hope it satisfied your requirement. If it is then up vote for this ans.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a custom div/class with width:100%; behind first two text-boxes.

**HTML :**

```
<form>

<div class="colored">
............
first two text-boxes
...........
</div>

................
rest all text-box/form
...............

<form>
```

**CSS :**

```
.colored{
float:left;
background-color-#000;
width:100%;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this..

```
input, input[type="text"]{
background-color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

do you mean this.....

```
 input{
    border:1px solid #ddd !important;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/LFLkp/